# Terraform Apply always modifies a Security Group in place

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

my Terraform project always seems to modify this `aws_security_group.jacobs_rds_security_group_tf` resource in-place when I run `terraform apply`.  Everything still works it just makes debugging weird when I always have an extra resource getting modified even though nothing about it is changing.

I have 2 security groups; 1 is for my RDS DB which whitelists incoming traffic, and the other is for tasks and it attaches to my ECS & Lambda tasks so they can access this RDS DB.  The Task Security Group is whitelisted in the RDS Security Group.

The RDS Security group (`aws_security_group.jacobs_rds_security_group_tf`) is the one that is always getting modified in-place.  Below is the code.

```
resource "aws_vpc" "jacobs_vpc_tf" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
  enable_dns_hostnames = true

}

resource "aws_security_group" "jacobs_task_security_group_tf"{
    name = "jacobs_security_group for tasks"
    description = "Connect Tasks to RDS"
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.jacobs_vpc_tf.id

    ingress {
    from_port        = 0
    to_port          = 0
    protocol         = "-1"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  }

    egress {
    from_port        = 0
    to_port          = 0
    protocol         = "-1"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "jacobs_rds_security_group_tf" {
  name        = "jacobs_security_group for rds"
  description = "Allow Jacobs Traffic to RDS"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.jacobs_vpc_tf.id

  ingress {
    description      = "Custom IP Addresses"
    from_port        = 5432
    to_port          = 5432
    protocol         = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks      = var.jacobs_cidr_block

  }

  ingress {
    description      = "Other Security Groups"
    from_port        = -1
    to_port          = -1
    protocol         = "all"
    security_groups  = [aws_security_group.jacobs_task_security_group_tf.id] # this should be changed to vpc_security_group_ids ?
  }


  # outbound
  egress {
    from_port        = 0
    to_port          = 0
    protocol         = "-1"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  }

}
```

[image]

I research this problem about once a month and screw around with the Terraform to try & fix it and have had no success.  The github issues I come across don't seem to apply to my setup, but maybe I'm missing something obvious?  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Just to make sure, aren't you creating an extra `aws_security_group_rule` somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your problem is that you have this ingress rule:

```
ingress {
    description      = "Other Security Groups"
    from_port        = -1
    to_port          = -1
    protocol         = "all"
    security_groups  = [aws_security_group.jacobs_task_security_group_tf.id]
  }
```

You have the `from_port` and `to_port` set to -1. You should set them to `0`. From the [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group#protocol):

> If you select a protocol of `-1` (semantically equivalent to `all`, which is not a valid value here), you must specify a `from_port` and `to_port` equal to `0`.

What is happening in this case is that Terraform (or the AWS API used by Terraform) will set them to `0`, without erroring out. Since there was a change after the `apply`, Terraform will try will detect it when you do a `plan` again.

Moreover, I think the docs are not accurate here, setting `all` to `protocol` is allowed here (at least with the Terraform version I've tried, `v1.0.11`, AWS provider version `3.70.0`).